# Custom login laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication

I have problem with custom login laravel. This is code for authenticate.
This code don't work. have you idea?

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Http\Response;
    use App\Models\Users;
    use DB;
    class LoginController extends Controller {
      public function dologin(Request $request){
    $email = $request->input('u_email');
    $password = $request->input('pwd1');
    // Check validation
   $checkLogin = DB::table('users')->where(['u_email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();
      if(count($checkLogin)  >0){
       echo "Login SuccessFull<br/>";;
      }else{
       echo "Login Faield Wrong Data Passed";
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: the webpage display Webpage don't work and in url find route login or in my web.php I don't use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that because passwords are hashed in Laravel. Use the [`attempt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users) method instead:

```
// Check validation
if (auth()->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    echo "Login SuccessFull<br/>";;
} else {
    echo "Login Failed Wrong Data Passed";
}
```

Comment: solved with code but with my password this result Login failed

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON this code will work if you create password using `bcrypt()` or `Hash::make()` methods.

Comment: okay. so why don't find my model in auth.php 
'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON I didn't understand the question in the previous comment, sorry.

Comment: in my auth.php I have this code:

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
and my problem.

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class '\App\User' not found
my class User don't found so this class exist in folder Models

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON did you delete or move `User` model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162361/discussion-between-tojo-rodialson-and-alexey-mezenin).

Comment: I don't delete my models. I add namespace App\Models; in my model User and same error

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON then in `config/auth.php` you also need to change the model namespace to make it work.

Comment: I use this namespace App\Models; for namespace

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON try to clear the cache then with `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: okay. This is my last question: why this error display Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Models\Users given, called in C:\wamp64\www\nosrepas\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 379

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON `User` must extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

Comment: how to do implement?

Comment: `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;` on the top of the class and then `class User extends Authenticatable`. It's like it's done in a standard `User` class.

Comment: great. thanks for helping. So if I add role user on my controller, I put in attemp or how?
if (auth()->attempt(['u_email' => $email, 'password' => $password] ) && $users->isAdmin) {
        
    } else {
        
    }

Comment: @TojoRODIALSON you should use middleware and policies to handle permissions.